# I released my Dart Web app but after deploying it bootstrap all.css was not found

Tags: dart, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-dart

I used webdev to build my Dart Angular web application with the following command:

```
webdev build -r
```

Everything works besides bootstrap, the browser gives error 404 not found for all.css file.
I checked on the build result and all.css does not exists, just the all.scss file.
Should web dev convert this sass file to regular css when it's releasing the application.
I have components that use scss files and I have no issue with them (I know they are compiled to my main.js file)
Any help I'd be thankful.

For now I logged into my local test and manually copied the resulting all.css with my chrome source into my build but I don't think I should do this every time I do a new build.

Comment: Did you add some config in your build.yaml file?
Which version of sass_builder are you using?

Comment: No I did not add a config in my build yaml, I'm using sass+builder 2.0.0

Comment: Do you have any error/warning message about sass compilation? Also try to update to sass_builder-2.1.2 to see if change something